# Returned False three time instead of one

Tags: python, implementation

```
def jump_to(self, position_piece, target_position):


    middle_position = Position((position_piece.line + target_position.line)/2, 
                               (position_piece.column + target_position.column)/2)

    if position_piece not in self.cases:
        return False
    elif (target_position not in position_piece.four_position_jumps() and
        target_position in self.cases):
        return False
    elif middle_position in self.cases:
        if self.cases[position_piece] == self.cases[middle_position]:
            return False

    return True
```

I have created the above function, but I realised I returned 3 times False. It looks bad implementation for me. Is it a fine implementation? How can I modify that code to make it more pythonic? I would be interested to know how to return False once instead of three.

Comment: Just set a variable called something like result = true, then change it result=false in the if statement and at the end return result.

Comment: To be honest, the way your code is layed out is readable - with no significantly long if statements.

Comment: Though you have a number of conditions to test that all return False, it is relatively clear and easy to follow this way. You could combine it into into a single `if` condition, but it would not likely be easier to follow. The big reason why this is probably better is because they are just doing a return. If they were each executing the same multiple lines of code that had to be copied in each (with the possibility for error if a change was needed) that would be a different situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @leopardxpreload's comment in that the multiple `False` returns is not the primary issue with your code, particularly since it does only have one `True` return.  I see your calculation of `middle_position` early in the code, just to ignore it in some situations, as a bigger issue:

```
def jump_to(self, position_piece, target_position):

    if position_piece not in self.cases:
        return False

    if target_position in self.cases and \
        target_position not in position_piece.four_position_jumps():
        return False

    line = (position_piece.line + target_position.line) / 2
    column = (position_piece.column + target_position.column) / 2

    middle_position = Position(line, column)

    if middle_position in self.cases:
        if self.cases[position_piece] == self.cases[middle_position]:
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: I would probably leave off the   `if middle_position in self.cases` pre-check like you had initially before the edit, but wrap the check in a try/except to catch it when `middle_position` is not in `self.cases`. It looks like a dictionary so you would want to catch the KeyError.

Comment: Changing the `elif`s to `if`s is better. However, I may be missing something here, but it looks like your code is incorrect since you have dropped the `target_position in self.cases` check from the second test. It is not clear to me how  `target_position not in position_piece.four_position_jumps()` incorporates that part of the `and`ed condition.

Comment: @GlennMackintosh, yes I accidentally dropped that clause which I originally combined with its duplicate (before posting) which disappeard in the OP's edit.  Though when adding it back just now, I reversed it as it seems more efficient to do the `in` and then function call should the `in` fail.  I don't like working on code I can't test just for this reason!

Answer (score 1):

This could be another way although I wouldn't say it's much more readable or intuitive and I have also written the code in a more minimalistic form for the example:

```py
cases = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
position_piece = 'w'
target_position = 'r'

def jump_to():
    check1 = not any([True if each_case == position_piece else False for each_case in cases])
    check2 = any([True if each_case == target_position else False for each_case in cases])
    return False if check1 or check2 else True

print(checker())
```

Note: because you are checking for `target_position in self.cases:` the `and` comparator means that just checking for this is enough to cover the cases.

Comment: This is clearly not more readable than the original.

Comment: @GlennMackintosh This is clearly pointed out... the question was for using one `False` statement.

Comment: True, you did point that out. As for the question, I interpreted the OP's focus to be the part where he asked `Is it a fine implementation?` and it is clearer and so better as is than the alternatives. You said yours was not much more readable, but I would disagree and say yours is significantly less readable.

Comment: @GlennMackintosh Guess that's the beauty of programming. Many solutions for a problem - and there is personal preference involved. Thank you for your opinion, very constructive, I learned so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is decent but could be improved upon using
@cdlane 's answer.

This answer aims to use a single point of exit. While it might be more readable then cdlane's answer. It is more complex and probably less maintanable then cdlane's answer, and you should use his/her answer instead. But here is how a single return could look like.

```
def jump_to(self, position_piece, target_position):
    middle_position = Position((position_piece.line + target_position.line)/2,
                                   (position_piece.column + target_position.column)/2)
    return (position_piece in self.cases
            and (not target_position in self.cases
                 or (target_position in position_piece.four_position_jumps()
                     and self.cases[position_piece] != self.cases[middle_position])))
```